# How to show multiple times icon in contact detail for my app icon like whatsapp

Tags: android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I am trying to show multiple rows as my app also support chat and call services. I want to show same like whatsap is doing as shown in below image.

I have implemented the sync adapter and all the other things using some help from different blogs. I have successfully added one row but i want multiple rows as we can see whatsap in that picture. I want to show multiple rows as shown in the picture.

[Please see this for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dONvO.jpg)

### For showing only one line, I was doing using the below code.

```
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
            builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, Constants.ACCOUNT_NAME);
            builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
            builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, contact.name);
            ops.add(builder.build());
  builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
            builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.ajay.contacts_4");
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, contact.name);
    builder.with Value(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "SyncProviderDemo Profile");
  builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "View profile");
            ops.add(builder.build());


            try {
                resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inserting only for one time using ContentProviderOperation.newInsert as you can see in questions. But when i add multiple time for same contact and then apply the batch.
Then one contact contains multiple rows.

> builder =
>   ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
>               builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
>   0);
>               builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
>              "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.ajay.contacts_4");
>               builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, contact.name);
>               builder.with Value(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "SyncProviderDemo Profile");
>               **builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Call " + number);**
>               ops.add(builder.build());
>
> builder =
>   ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
>               builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
>   0);
>               builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
>              "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.ajay.contacts_4");
>               builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, contact.name);
>               builder.with Value(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "SyncProviderDemo Profile");
>               **builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Message" + number);**
>               ops.add(builder.build());
>            try {
>                   resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
>               } catch (Exception e) {
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               }